# Creating Events in Mono.Cecil

Tags: c#, events, mono, il, mono.cecil

I've been trying to create events with Mono.Cecil, but not sure how.

```
EventDefinition newEvent = new EventDefinition("newEvent", 
                                               Mono.Cecil.EventAttributes.None, 
                                               someRefToTheEventHandlerDelegate);
```

I'm stuck at the addon and removeon part. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add the MethodDefinition for "add_newEvent" and "remove_newEvent" and assign them to the newEvent instance.

An easy way to learn how Cecil works and how it wants things to be set up is to:

1) compile what you want in an assembly (e.g. your event as you wish it);

2) load it with Mono.Cecil

3) use a debugger (MonoDevelop or VisualStudio will do) to see how things are populated;

4) codify the same into your application;

5) profit! ;-)

Comment: I was hoping not having to go through that kind of stage ^^ I'll try it when I get back from school. Thanks anyway!

Comment: it's not really complicated - you already know (1), Assembly.ReadDefinition(fileName) will do (2), if you're inside an IDE you can drill down the debugger watches to see the MainModule, then the Type[x], then the Events[y] which will show the add and remove methods. (4) is a few lines of code, (5) is your prize ;-) and best of all this solution can be applied to almost anything you'll ever need to do with Cecil!

Comment: Thanks, apart from codifying the body cods, what else needs to be taken into consideration?